# Does esotericism make sense in this context or is there a better word?

Tags: single-word-requests

So I'm trying to find a word/phrase that fits the context of like "a knowledge that can only be truly understood by lived experience", it seems like 'esoteric' kind of fits, but from what I've seen esotericism has more to do with educational specialization instead of just like lived experience.

Some examples of the context I'm talking about would be like: the perspective of someone who suffers from mental health, things like being poor/impoverished, being in an abusive relationship, etc.

I've played around with words like 'wisdom' and 'empathy', but they don't really seem to fit.

Comment: Is there a chance that you're overlooking _experience_ here? That seems to be the word you're after.

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/definition/esoteric

Comment: @user405662 ahm possibly, I could probably make like a roundabout way of saying it using 'experience', I was just wondering if there was like a more concise way of doing it with only a single word

Comment: @Cascabel "Intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialized knowledge or interest." From what I understand 'specialized' means more like you've been trained to do something rather than lived through something, I'm not sure if this difference is significant or not

Comment: @Cascabel I too wondered about *esoteric* - and *recondite*. But both relate to specialised knowledge and neither quite fits the specification of "lived experience", does it?

Comment: @displayelk445 The difference is significant. Often wisdom gained through experience and education are seen as diametrical opposites.

Comment: *Esoteric* would definitely be a wrong word to use here, among other reasons, because it implies that the knowledge in question is possessed by a very small number of people, while it is possible for quite a few people to have some 'knowledge that can only be truly understood by lived experience'.

Comment: You need to “walk in their shoes” to understand them.

Comment: There is no obvious research that the OP could have done to make the question more focused. The question is clearly formulated and well within the scope of this site. I believe that the answer to it is that there is no single word or short phrase that has precisely this meaning, but that is not a reason for closing the question.

Comment: The usual term is **experiential knowledge**. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiential_knowledge#:~:text=Experiential%20knowledge%20is%20knowledge%20gained,knowledge%2C%20and%20with%20practical%20knowledge.) says: _Experiential knowledge is knowledge gained through experience, as opposed to a priori (before experience) knowledge: it can also be contrasted both with propositional (textbook) knowledge, and with practical knowledge._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the concept that the OP has in mind is narrower than *experiential knowledge*. A well-to-do sociologist conducting systematic empirical research into some aspect of poverty can thereby gain experiential knowledge about poverty, but that wouldn't be the kind of knowledge about poverty that one gets from actually living in poverty.

Comment: @jsw29 You'd better tell the [American Psychological Association](https://dictionary.apa.org/experiential-knowledge) they've got it wrong.  '**experiential knowledge**: 
understanding and expertise that emerge from life experience rather than from formal education or professional training. For example, members of self-help groups draw upon experiential knowledge in supporting and helping each other.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the APA definition (although not very well worded) indeed tries to capture the concept that the OP has in mind (and could provide an answer to the question), but it is different from the Wikipedia definitions quoted in your earlier comment. The Wikipedia definitions contrast experiential knowledge with a priori knowledge and textbook knowledge; the knowledge obtained by systematic empirical research is neither a priori nor textbook knowledge, and is thus experiential in the Wikipedia sense, but not in the APA sense.

Answer (score 1):

you might be looking for the word "experiential" as [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/experiential) defines it:

> Relating to or having experience; derived from experience; empirical.

you can also use the word ["empirical"](https://www.wordnik.com/words/empirical):

> Pertaining to, derived from, or testable by observations made using
> the physical senses or using instruments which extend the senses.

Comment: Please see the comments by Mr. Ashworth, who first proposed *experiential*, and myself, below the question.